# Return JSON based on not matching certain values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working on a `JSON` in `javascript` and want to return only values that don't contain the article word. For the below `JSON`

```
var json = [
    {
        id: 1,
        path: ["home>blog","home>article"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        path: ["home>blog"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        path: ["home>blog"]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        path: ["home>blog","home>article"]
    },
]
```

And I want to get the final result as -

```
var final = [
    {
        id: 2,
        path: ["home>blog"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        path: ["home>blog"]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve the result?

Comment: Use `Array#filter` and `Array#some` + `String#includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) you achieve that.

Try the following:

```js
const json = [{ id: 1, path: ["home>blog","home>article"] }, { id: 2, path: ["home>blog"] }, { id: 3, path: ["home>blog"] }, { id: 4, path: ["home>blog","home>article"] }];

const result = json.filter(e => !e.path.some(s => s.includes('article')));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code works

```
const final = json.filter(obj=>{
 for(const path of obj.path){
 if(path.includes('article') return false;
 }
return true;
});
```